# ERROR -[ getFieldName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance while starting IOS simulator for Appcelerator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, titanium, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to compile an Appcelerator Titanium application using xCode 11.5 in order to deploy to AppStore. While starting building the application I get this error.

I mention that the app worked perfectly while building with appc 8.0.0, titanium sdk 7.5.2 and Mojave with xCode 9 or Catalina with xcode 10.

Is there something that I am missing? What should I modify to build for xCode 11.5 ?

**Environment versions:**
macOS Catalina 10.15.5, xCode 11.5, titanium sdk 9.0.3.GA, appc 8.0.0, node v12.0.0

**Behaviour:**
Simulator starts, application shows start screen then application disappears and simulator shows home screen.

**Startup log**

```
user@users-MacBook-Pro project % appc "run" "--platform" "ios" "--log-level" "info" "--project-dir" "/Users/Shared/companyDEV/CLONE/project" "--target" "simulator" "--device-id" "6FFF391B-EE31-408F-A4E7-7A0B0F281B07" "--liveview"
    Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 8.0.0
    Copyright (c) 2014-2020, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

    6/17/2020, 4:26:13 PM

    Operating System
      Name                        = Mac OS X
      Version                     = 10.15.5
      Architecture                = 64bit
      # CPUs                      = 16
      Memory                      = 17179869184

    Node.js
      Node.js Version             = 12.0.0
      npm Version                 = 6.9.0

    Titanium CLI
      CLI Version                 = 5.2.2

    Titanium SDK
      SDK Version                 = 9.0.3.GA
      SDK Path                    = /Users/user/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.0.3.GA
      Target Platform             = iphone

    Command
      /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/bin/node /Users/user/.appcelerator/install/8.0.0/package/node_modules/titanium/lib/titanium.js build --platform ios --log-level info --project-dir /Users/Shared/companyDEV/CLONE/project --target simulator --device-id 6FFF391B-EE31-408F-A4E7-7A0B0F281B07 --liveview --config-file /var/folders/8y/85bybzrx06l23bwx4ym9m1xr0000gn/T/build-1592400370504.json --no-banner --project-dir /Users/Shared/companyDEV/CLONE/project

    [INFO]  Found Titanium module id=com.company version=0.2 platform=ios deploy-type=development path=/Users/Shared/companyDEV/CLONE/project/modules/iphone/com.company/0.2
    [INFO]  Found Titanium module id=com.0x82.webserver version=0.15 platform=ios deploy-type=development path=/Users/Shared/companyDEV/CLONE/project/modules/iphone/com.0x82.webserver/0.15
    [INFO]  Found Titanium module id=com.logicallabs.bluetoothle version=1.2.8 platform=ios deploy-type=development path=/Users/Shared/companyDEV/CLONE/project/modules/iphone/com.logicallabs.bluetoothle/1.2.8
    [INFO]  Found Titanium module id=com.company.printer version=1.0.0 platform=ios deploy-type=development path=/Users/Shared/companyDEV/CLONE/project/modules/iphone/com.company.printer/1.0.0
    [INFO]  Deploy type: development
    [INFO]  Building for target: simulator
    [INFO]  Building using iOS SDK: 13.5
    [INFO]  Building for iOS Simulator: iPad Air (3rd generation)
    [INFO]  Building for device family: ipad
    [INFO]  Team ID: n/a
    [INFO]  Minimum iOS version: 10.0
    [INFO]  Logging disabled
    [INFO]  Debugging disabled
    [INFO]  Profiler disabled
    [INFO]  Set to copy files instead of symlinking
    [INFO]  Transpile javascript: true
    [INFO]  Generate source maps: true
    [INFO]  Initializing the build directory
    [INFO]  Creating Xcode project
    [INFO]  Creating Entitlements.plist
    [INFO]  Creating Info.plist
    [WARN]  Launch images are deprecated by Xcode 11 and you will need to adopt a storyboard-based launch screen
    [INFO]  Copying custom Info.plist from project directory
    [INFO]  Disabling ATS
    [WARN]  Removing custom Info.plist "CFBundleIconFiles" since we now use an asset catalog for app icons.
    [INFO]  Creating main.m
    [INFO]  Creating Xcode config files
    [INFO]  Copying Titanium libraries
    [INFO]  Copying Titanium iOS files
    [INFO]  Creating debugger and profiler plists
    [INFO]  Analyzing Resources directory
    [INFO]  Analyzing platform files
    [INFO]  Analyzing module files
    [INFO]  Analyzing localized launch images
    [INFO]  Analyzing CommonJS modules
    [INFO]  Creating asset catalog
    [INFO]  Creating app icon set
    [INFO]  Creating launch image set
    [INFO]  App thinning disabled, skipping asset image sets
    [INFO]  Processing JavaScript files
    [INFO]  Writing app properties
    [INFO]  Writing bootstrap json
    [INFO]  Writing i18n files
    [INFO]  Processing Titanium symbols
    [INFO]  Removing files
    [INFO]  Writing index.json with listing of JS/JSON files
    [INFO]  Skipping xcodebuild
    [INFO]  Finished building the application in 720ms
    [LiveView] version 1.5.0
    [INFO]  Launching iOS Simulator
    [LiveView] File Server Started on 0.0.0.0:8324
    [LiveView] Event Server Started on 0.0.0.0:8323
    -- Start simulator log -------------------------------------------------------
    [LiveView] Client connected
    [INFO]  company 6.7.115 (Powered by Titanium 9.0.3.0b2fb28f0c)
    [INFO]  Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
    [INFO]  [object ComcompanyModule] loaded
    [INFO]  module is => [object ComcompanyModule]
    [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /Users/Shared/companyDEV/CLONE/project/Resources/ui/widgets/customWidgets.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
    [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /Users/Shared/companyDEV/CLONE/project/Resources/ui/controllers/controllers.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
    [INFO]  [object Com0x82WebserverModule] loaded
    [WARN]  Automatic setter methods for properties are deprecated in SDK 8.0.0 and will be removed in SDK 10.0.0. Please modify the property in standard JS style: obj.disconnectsInBackground = value; or obj['disconnectsInBackground'] = value;
    [ERROR] [GRAYLOG] Settings from graylog.settings successfully loaded
    [ERROR] [GRAYLOG] Logging is not activated!!!
    [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /Users/Shared/companyDEV/CLONE/project/Resources/engine/shift.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
    [LiveView] Client disconnected
    [ERROR] -[TiDatabaseResultSetProxy getFieldName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000340f400
    [ERROR] Script Error {
    [ERROR]     column = 35;
    [ERROR]     line = 1489;
    [ERROR]     message = "-[TiDatabaseResultSetProxy getFieldName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000340f400";
    [ERROR]     nativeStack = (
    [ERROR]         0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3cf0e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    [ERROR]         1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50ba89b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
    [ERROR]         2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e5dc34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    [ERROR]         3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e416b6 ___forwarding___ + 838
    [ERROR]         4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e43bf8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    [ERROR]         5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e43e8c __invoking___ + 140
    [ERROR]         6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e41071 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 321
    [ERROR]         7   JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c823bb _ZN3JSC24ObjCCallbackFunctionImpl4callEP9JSContextP13OpaqueJSValuemPKPKS3_PS6_ + 411
    [ERROR]         8   JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c81de7 _ZN3JSCL34objCCallbackFunctionCallAsFunctionEPK15OpaqueJSContextP13OpaqueJSValueS4_mPKPKS3_PS6_ + 231
    [ERROR]         9   JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c8158f _ZN3JSC19APICallbackFunction4callINS_20ObjCCallbackFunctionEEExPNS_14JSGlobalObjectEPNS_9CallFrameE + 575
    [ERROR]         10  ???                                 0x000026f315401027 0x0 + 42825475428391
    [ERROR]         11  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         12  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         13  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e6cd llint_entry + 93216
    [ERROR]         14  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e6cd llint_entry + 93216
    [ERROR]         15  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e6cd llint_entry + 93216
    [ERROR]         16  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         17  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         18  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         19  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         20  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         21  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         22  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         23  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         24  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         25  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         26  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         27  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4f332 llint_entry + 96389
    [ERROR]         28  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         29  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         30  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         31  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4f332 llint_entry + 96389
    [ERROR]         32  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         33  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         34  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e6cd llint_entry + 93216
    [ERROR]         35  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         36  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         37  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         38  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         39  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         40  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c378ff vmEntryToJavaScript + 200
    [ERROR]         41  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff2706d000 _ZN3JSC11Interpreter14executeProgramERKNS_10SourceCodeEPNS_14JSGlobalObjectEPNS_8JSObjectE + 12480
    [ERROR]         42  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff272dff6f _ZN3JSC8evaluateEPNS_14JSGlobalObjectERKNS_10SourceCodeENS_7JSValueERN3WTF8NakedPtrINS_9ExceptionEEE + 271
    [ERROR]         43  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c88aa9 JSEvaluateScript + 713
    [ERROR]         44  TitaniumKit                         0x0000000106a2c9ec -[KrollEval jsInvokeInContext:exception:] + 175
    [ERROR]         45  TitaniumKit                         0x00000001069f6778 -[KrollBridge loadCommonJSModule:withSourceURL:] + 307
    [ERROR]         46  TitaniumKit                         0x00000001069f70ef -[KrollBridge loadJavascriptText:fromFile:withContext:] + 68
    [ERROR]         47  TitaniumKit                         0x00000001069f847f -[KrollBridge require:path:] + 377
    [ERROR]         48  TitaniumKit                         0x0000000106a2d7e4 CommonJSRequireCallback + 106
    [ERROR]         49  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c89ea8 _ZN3JSC19APICallbackFunction4callINS_18JSCallbackFunctionEEExPNS_14JSGlobalObjectEPNS_9CallFrameE + 568
    [ERROR]         50  ???                                 0x000026f315401027 0x0 + 42825475428391
    [ERROR]         51  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         52  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e74d llint_entry + 93344
    [ERROR]         53  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c4e8ca llint_entry + 93725
    [ERROR]         54  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c378ff vmEntryToJavaScript + 200
    [ERROR]         55  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff2706d000 _ZN3JSC11Interpreter14executeProgramERKNS_10SourceCodeEPNS_14JSGlobalObjectEPNS_8JSObjectE + 12480
    [ERROR]         56  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff272dff6f _ZN3JSC8evaluateEPNS_14JSGlobalObjectERKNS_10SourceCodeENS_7JSValueERN3WTF8NakedPtrINS_9ExceptionEEE + 271
    [ERROR]         57  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff26c88aa9 JSEvaluateScript + 713
    [ERROR]         58  TitaniumKit                         0x00000001069f4b42 -[KrollBridge evalFileOnThread:context:] + 719
    [ERROR]         59  TitaniumKit                         0x0000000106a2c69f -[KrollInvocation invoke:] + 58
    [ERROR]         60  TitaniumKit                         0x0000000106a2d026 -[KrollContext invoke:] + 109
    [ERROR]         61  TitaniumKit                         0x00000001069f4c6d -[KrollBridge evalFile:callback:selector:] + 55
    [ERROR]         62  TitaniumKit                         0x00000001069f5d5f -[KrollBridge didStartNewContext:] + 3574
    [ERROR]         63  TitaniumKit                         0x0000000106a2d752 -[KrollContext main] + 1037
    [ERROR]         64  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff519e2951 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    [ERROR]         65  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff519e38cb _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    [ERROR]         66  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff519efcdb _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1042
    [ERROR]         67  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da0909 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    [ERROR]         68  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9b459 __CFRunLoopRun + 2041
    [ERROR]         69  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9a944 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
    [ERROR]         70  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38ba6c1a GSEventRunModal + 139
    [ERROR]         71  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48c8b9ec UIApplicationMain + 1605
    [ERROR]         72  company                                0x000000010605df2b main + 1115
    [ERROR]         73  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff51a231fd start + 1
    [ERROR] );
    [ERROR]     sourceURL = undefined;
    [ERROR]     stack = "[native code]\nrowField\nexecuteResultset\ngetLastOrderIx\ninit\ncreateDatasource\ncurrentStore\nopen\nexecuteResultset\ngetLastOrderIx\ninit\ncreateDatasource\nlocalStore\nexportModePinSet\nexpertMode\ngetExpandableMenuItemsForAdmin\nHomeView\n\n\nafterModelLoaded\nApplicationWindow\n\nanonymous\nfile:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6FFF391B-EE31-408F-A4E7-7A0B0F281B07/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/15B67F13-96F5-417B-8BA7-AB799B123224/company.app/app.js:728:9\nfile:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6FFF391B-EE31-408F-A4E7-7A0B0F281B07/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/15B67F13-96F5-417B-8BA7-AB799B123224/company.app/app.js:586:25\nfile:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6FFF391B-EE31-408F-A4E7-7A0B0F281B07/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/15B67F13-96F5-417B-8BA7-AB799B123224/company.app/app.js:493:19\nfile:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6FFF391B-EE31-408F-A4E7-7A0B0F281B07/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/15B67F13-96F5-417B-8BA7-AB799B123224/company.app/app.js:425:25\nfile:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6FFF391B-EE31-408F-A4E7-7A0B0F281B07/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/15B67F13-96F5-417B-8BA7-AB799B123224/company.app/app.js:763:15\nfile:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6FFF391B-EE31-408F-A4E7-7A0B0F281B07/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/15B67F13-96F5-417B-8BA7-AB799B123224/company.app/app.js:768:3\nglobal code@file:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6FFF391B-EE31-408F-A4E7-7A0B0F281B07/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/15B67F13-96F5-417B-8BA7-AB799B123224/company.app/app.js:771:70\nrequire@[native code]\nfile:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6FFF391B-EE31-408F-A4E7-7A0B0F281B07/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/15B67F13-96F5-417B-8BA7-AB799B123224/company.app/ti.main.js:13073:10\nloadAsync@file:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6FFF391B-EE31-408F-A4E7-7A0B0F281B07/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/15B67F13-96F5-417B-8BA7-AB799B123224/company.app/ti.main.js:13001:13\nglobal code@file:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6FFF391B-EE31-408F-A4E7-7A0B0F281B07/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/15B67F13-96F5-417B-8BA7-AB799B123224/company.app/ti.main.js:13070:10";
    [ERROR] } 
    [ERROR] -[TiDatabaseResultSetProxy getFieldName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000340ab00
    [INFO]  Application started
```

**Show more info using appc ti info -t iOS:**

```
user@users-MacBook-Pro project % appc ti info -t iOS 
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 8.0.0
Copyright (c) 2014-2020, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

 Xcode 
   11.5 (build 11E608c) - Xcode default 
    Install Location          =  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer 
    iOS SDKs                  =  13.5 
    iOS Simulators            =  10.2, 10.3, 11.2, 11.4, 12.0, 12.2, 13.0, 13.4, 13.5 
    Watch SDKs                =  6.2 
    Watch Simulators          =  6.2 
    Supported by TiSDK 9.0.3.GA =  yes 
    EULA Accepted             =  yes 
    Teams                     =  none 

 iOS Keychains 
  login.keychain-db           =  /Users/user/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db 
  System.keychain             =  /Library/Keychains/System.keychain 

 iOS Development Certificates 
 /Library/Keychains/System.keychain 
   iPhone Developer: developer name (E733CC9A49) 
    Not valid before          =  3/11/2020 10:02 AM 
    Not valid after           =  3/11/2021 10:02 AM 

 iOS App Store Distribution Certificates 
   None 

 Apple WWDR Certificate 
  Apple WWDR                  =  installed 

 Development iOS Provisioning Profiles 
   adev2021_2 
    UUID                      =  86a9f488-024e-4e78-9b08-b99a42d49b75 
    App Prefix                =  4W3Z997ZYM 
    App Id                    =  com.companyero.* 
    Date Created              =  4/1/2020 5:26 PM 
    Date Expired              =  4/1/2021 5:26 PM 
    Managed                   =  No 
   adev2021_4 
    UUID                      =  27d9c2d3-2a1e-4757-8f34-d398b055fe36 
    App Prefix                =  4W3Z997ZYM 
    App Id                    =  com.companyero.* 
    Date Created              =  6/4/2020 5:33 PM 
    Date Expired              =  6/4/2021 5:33 PM 
    Managed                   =  No 

 App Store Distribution iOS Provisioning Profiles 
   None 

 Ad Hoc iOS Provisioning Profiles 
   None 

 Enterprise Ad Hoc iOS Provisioning Profiles 
   None 

 iOS Simulators 
 10.3 ...
 11.2 ...
 11.4 ...
 12.0 ...
 12.2 ...
 13.0 ...
 13.4 ...
 13.5 ...
 iOS Issues 
    !     Unable to find any valid iOS adhoc provisioning profiles.
     This will prevent you from packaging apps for adhoc distribution.
     You will need to log in to  http://appcelerator.com/ios-dist-certs  with your Apple Developer
     account, then create, download, and install a profile.

    !     Unable to find any valid iOS distribution provisioning profiles.
     This will prevent you from packaging apps for AppStore distribution.
     You will need to log in to  http://appcelerator.com/ios-dist-certs  with your Apple Developer
     account, then create, download, and install a profile.

    !     Unable to find any valid iOS production distribution certificates.
     This will prevent you from packaging apps for distribution.
     You will need to log in to  http://appcelerator.com/ios-dist-certs  with your Apple Developer
     account, then create, download, and install a certificate.
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: Searched for where "getFieldName" was used and replaced it with "fieldName".

It seems that the TiDatabaseResultSetProxy.m library has changed in titanium sdk 8.
See more:
https://github.com/daicham/mytwitterclient/blob/master/build/iphone/Classes/TiDatabaseResultSetProxy.m

Comment: The link is a custom module that is 9 years old. Did you use that and the error was inside this module? Where did you search and replace those names? Would be interesting for other people who have this error and want to solve it